# for loop to find position where the sum of the actual value and the next one is greater than x

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a for loop that iterates over a vector. As soon as it finds a position where the sum of the actual value at that position and the next one is above 100 in this example, it should print the index number and break.

I use the following example vector

`v <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE);`

so far I created

```
for (index in 1:length(v)){
  if (sum(v[index]+v[index+1]) > 100){
    print(sprintf("found in %s", v[index]));
  }
  if (sum(v[index]+v[index+1]) > 101) break
};
```

How do make sure the loop breaks after the printing the first position found taking into consideration that I am looking for the value of one position plus the next one (do I break at the first or the one after that since it should also be considered?)

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

- If you want to add `x` and `y` together, you can use `x + y` or `sum(x, y)`. They're different if `x` and `y` are vectors (try it and see!). But if `x` and `y` are both single values (length 1), they are the same. `sum(v[index]+v[index+1])` seems redundant - keep it simple and use one or the other.
- > How do make sure the loop breaks after the printing the first position found?

  Put the `break` right after `print()`.
- > ...taking into consideration that I am looking for the value of one position plus the next one

  That's what your `if()` statement does. Because you use both `v[index]` and `v[index + 1]`, you are considering both already.
- If you get to the last iteration of the loop where `index = length(v)`, then `v[index + 1]` will give an out-of-bounds error. So you should only loop to the second-to-last element.
- Welcome to R, where semicolons aren't needed!

So, a cleaned up for loop might look like this:

```
for (index in 1:(length(v) - 1)){
  if (v[index] + v[index + 1] > 100){
    print(sprintf("found in %s", v[index]))
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Gregor for the extensive response, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `for` loop :

```
v <- c(23, 45, 67, 33, 45)
which.max(head(v, -1) + tail(v, -1) > 100)
#[1] 2
```

This returns the first index of the pair where sum becomes more than 100.

---

Variations of the above are :

```
which.max(v[-1] + v[-length(v)] > 100)
which.max(v + dplyr::lead(v) > 100)
which.max(v + data.table::shift(v, type = 'lead') > 100)
which.max(v + dplyr::lag(v) > 100) - 1
which.max(v + data.table::shift(v) > 100) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. However, I wanted to use a for loop in this case.